# Is possible to get non oauth2 tokens with wso2 Identity Server and use it with wso2 APIManager?

Tags: wso2

Is there any way to use WSO2 APIManager and Identity Server to securize a backend API using non oauth2 tokens due to no Web interaction is expected?

Comment: what do you mean by "no Web interaction is expected"?

Comment: The user is not going to log in a web or use a web application, just HTTP APIs

Comment: Users can call /token API and get OAuth tokens.

Comment: But calling /token API to get oauth token user is going to be in the redirect flow, isn't it?